# How to pass on variables for Google Ecommerce Tracking?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm trying to setup Google Ecommerce tracking using a third-party booking system for a restaurant. I can only add html or javascript (in this case Analytics code) in a specific place on the thank-you-page after transaction details.

My question is how can i pass data from booking system output on to Google Ecommerce tracking variables?

**Output from Booking system:**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var dataLayer = typeof dataLayer === "undefined" ? [] : dataLayer;

        dataLayer.push({
            "email": "exampled@example.com",
            "idRestaurant": "202072",
            "nbReservation": "",
            "nbPAX": "5",
            "date": "2017-01-13 18:30:00",
            "event": "booking",
            "idCampaignHash": "15271-59f",
            "caBrut": "10",
            "idResa": "75655429",
            "typePromo": "Enkel reservation"
        });
        var mediaLayer = [].concat(dataLayer);
        for(var i=0;i<mediaLayer.length;i++){
            if(mediaLayer[i]['event']&&mediaLayer[i]['event'].match(/^gtm\./) ){
                mediaLayer.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
                        mediaLayer.push({
                "email": "example@example.com",
                "event": "nouveauLead"
            });
            dataLayer.push({
                "aboTypeLabel": "Offers",
                "event": "inscritNewsletter"
            });
            dataLayer.push({
                "aboTypeLabel": "Info",
                "event": "inscritNewsletter"
            });



                        dataLayer.push({
        'typeModule': "MRG"
    });

    var pageCategory = 'Thank_you_normal';
    dataLayer.push({
        'pageCategory': pageCategory
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var dataLayer = typeof dataLayer === "undefined" ? [] : dataLayer;
    dataLayer.push({
        'idRestaurant': "12345",
        "nameRestaurant": "Test Restaurant",
        "nameProvider": "",
        "idCampaignHash": "15271-59f"
    });
    dataLayer.push({
        'typeModule': "MRG"
    });
</script>
```

**My Javascript (Analytics Tracking code) after the code above:**

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-11111-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
  ga('require', 'ecommerce');

  ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
  'id': '[idResa]',        // Booking id
  'quantity': '[nbPAX]',   // Number of people.

typePromo
});
ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
  'id': '[idResa]',         // Booking id
  'name': '[typePromo]',    // Type of menu
});
ga('ecommerce:send');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `dataLayer` is a global variable so you can easily access the data stored in it: take the first element `dataLayer[0]` or iterate through elements and find what you need (by checking if `nbPAX` field exists or etc)

***UPDATED***

Here is a few examples:

1 to pass individual parameters from first item of `dataLayer` array

```
ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', { quantity : dataLayer[0].nbPAX, id : dataLayer[0].idResa })

ga('ecommerce:addItem', { id: dataLayer[0].idResa, name : dataLayer[0].typePromo });

ga('ecommerce:send');
```

2 Or if you not sure that first item contains necessary information you can filter items and send info to google analytics for each of it for example

```
//i.e. get all items with parameter idResa
let items = dataLayer.filter(function(item){ return item && item.idResa })

items.forEach(function(item){ 

    ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', { quantity : item.nbPAX, id : item.idResa })
    ga('ecommerce:addItem', { id: item.idResa, name : item.typePromo });
    ga('ecommerce:send');

})
```

Comment: for sure, check the answer again, i provided some examples

Answer (score 0):

The output of the booking system is actually in the Google Tag Manager format. This requires some setup on your side.

See https://www.google.com/tagmanager/ for some more info. You can also combine it with analytics from there.

After this you can add the Tag Manager script to your page, and your tags should be pushed to the Tag Manager.

Comment: Won't it be a problem that the GTM-code comes after the booking output system?
Read something about it here:
https://www.optimizesmart.com/implementing-e-commerce-tracking-google-tag-manager/

Comment: Well, as far as I know, you first fill the datalayer, and then add the GTM code to the page. It's explained here in the dev-guide: https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide